# Omit first 5 lines in .LOG file using batch processor

Tags: csv, batch-file

I’ve created a .bat file which captures all .log files in its directory and compiles them all into one .csv file. I want it to omit, not delete, the first 5 lines of each file while compiling, thus preserving the original file and leaving the lines out in the generated .csv file.

> PLEASE NOTE: I am simply using the .csv file to hold the compiled .log files. I know that the intended result bears no resemblance to an actual .csv file, I will process the file in excel to seperate the values.

.LOG File (' indicates lines to delete - not actually present in these lines in the file):

```
'20160201
'Time        Side     Serial #        Active Current      Idle Current   OK/NOK
'----------- -------- --------------- ------------------- -------------- ---
'    
'    
00:00:23    Left     4EEFD9     6.59418mA           0.00003mA      OK
00:00:23    Right    4EEFEF     6.85377mA           0.00001mA      OK
```

.CSV Output File:

```
00:00:23    Left     4EEFD9     6.59418mA           0.00003mA      OK     
00:00:23    Right    4EEFEF     6.85377mA           0.00001mA      OK     
00:00:44    Left     4EEFDC     6.32207mA           0.00004mA      OK     
00:00:44    Right    4EEF77     6.66909mA           0.00006mA      OK     
00:01:00    Left     4EEFB1     6.31158mA           0.00001mA      OK     
00:01:00    Right    4EEFA5     6.54818mA           0.00003mA      OK     
00:01:17    Left     4EEFA9     6.52762mA           0.00006mA      OK
```

Here's the code I used:

```
rem Script to process .log files to remove first five lines.
for %%I in (*.log) do for /f "delims=, tokens=* skip=5" %%x in (%%I) do echo %%x >> "%%I.new"

rem Script to compile .log files into .csv file.
for %%f in (*.log.new) do CALL :label "%%f" "results.csv"

:label

set resultfile=%2
type %1 >> %resultfile%
echo ; >> %resultfile%

exit/b
```

It manages to process the .log file the way I want, but it takes forever to do, since each file contains close to 10,000 lines and the batch processor copies each line to the new file. Is there a better way to have it simply ignore those first 5 lines?

---

EDIT 1:

Incorporating the original batch script provided by Aacini provides the following result:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "=" 

C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "=" 

C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "=" 

C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "=" 

C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "=" 
00:00:23    Left     4EEFD9     6.59418mA           0.00003mA      OK     
00:00:23    Right    4EEFEF     6.85377mA           0.00001mA      OK     
00:00:44    Left     4EEFDC     6.32207mA           0.00004mA      OK     
00:00:44    Right    4EEF77     6.66909mA           0.00006mA      OK     
...
```

NOTE: The processor no longer can run more than one .log file. It stops mid-execution after the first file. At this point I have to run two .bat files. First the one using Aacini's code (see his answer) and then this, as I could not combine the two:

```
rem Script to compile .log files into .csv file.
for %%f in (*.log) do CALL :label "%%f" "results.csv"

    :label

    set resultfile=%2
    type %1 >> %resultfile%
    echo ; >> %resultfile%

exit/b
```

Using Aacini's updated code I got the same result as my original code and much faster, however it still stops after the first .log file, and the last line of the .csv file now shows the following: `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`.

---

EDIT 2:

Using dbenham's first code solution I got the same result as my original code. However, the second code gave this result:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop>(
for /F "skip=5 usebackq delims=" %L in ("20160201.log") do echo(%L  
 echo ; 
) 

C:\Users\...\Desktop>echo(00:00:23    Left     4EEFD9     6.59418mA           0.00003mA      OK      
00:00:23    Left     4EEFD9     6.59418mA           0.00003mA      OK     

C:\Users\...\Desktop>echo(00:00:23    Right    4EEFEF     6.85377mA           0.00001mA      OK      
00:00:23    Right    4EEFEF     6.85377mA           0.00001mA      OK     

C:\Users\...\Desktop>echo(00:00:44    Left     4EEFDC     6.32207mA           0.00004mA      OK      
00:00:44    Left     4EEFDC     6.32207mA           0.00004mA      OK
```

And the third code gave this result:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop>(
more +5 "20160201.log"  
 echo ; 
) 
00:00:23    Left     4EEFD9     6.59418mA           0.00003mA      OK     
00:00:23    Right    4EEFEF     6.85377mA           0.00001mA      OK     
00:00:44    Left     4EEFDC     6.32207mA           0.00004mA      OK     
00:00:44    Right    4EEF77     6.66909mA           0.00006mA      OK
```

---

EDIT 3:

I was missing the `@echo off`. dbenham's updated 3rd script does the trick.

Comment: Does each line-you-don't-want start with a `'` as in the example you've shown?

Comment: I agree with Magoo.  `findstr /v "'" logfile >>outfile` would be much easier.

Comment: @Magoo - They unfortunately do not (I wish they did). @rojo - Do you think there would be a way to make that work even without the `'`?

Comment: @rojo - Ok, really dumb idea, but I thought of something based on what you suggested. Is there a way I could add the `'` or some similar distinguishable character to the first five lines and then use `findstr` to filter it back out? Seems redundant, I know, but maybe it will work? Batch is not my strong suite so I bow to greater wisdom.

Comment: You are free to name your output as you see fit, but your output has absolutely no resemblance to CSV format.

Comment: @dbenham - Yes, I know. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: @ckemmann just a little question: are you aware, what `@echo off` does?

Comment: @Stephan - No, I unfortunately am not. This is the first time I've worked with batch scripts.

Comment: `echo off` supresses code repetition. That are the additional lines you see when you run dbenhams or Aacinis code. Command repetition is very good to debug your code, but once the code runs fine, supression makes sense to keep the output clear. That's so basic, they probably couldn't imagine, you do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot fathom why you used an intermediate file. And your code defines a `str` variable, but never uses it.

Unless there is more important code that you are not sharing, then I believe all you need is the following: (Note, I am preserving your output name, but the output you have shown is ***not*** in CSV format.)

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.log) do (
  for /f "skip=5 delims=" %%L in (%%F) do echo %%L >>results.csv
  echo ; >>results.csv
)
```

Performance can be dramatically improved by redirecting only once. I'm assuming you want to start with an empty output file, so a single redirection allows you to use `>` instead of `>>`. I've made a number of other changes to improve reliability.

```
@echo off
>results.csv (
  for %%F in (*.log) do (
    for /f "skip=5 usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%F") do echo(%%L
    echo ;
  )
)
```

Assuming that your log file does not contain TAB characters, and no single log file exceeds ~64,000 lines, then you can use MORE to skip the first 5 lines of each file. This is *much* faster.

```
@echo off
>results.csv (
  for %%F in (*.log) do (
    more +5 "%%F"
    echo ;
  )
)
```

MORE will not pause because the output has been redirected to a file, although it will pause if you exceed ~64,000 lines. Any TAB characters will be converted into a series of spaces.

Comment: The `str` variable was there because I had copied the original code from a simple .txt to .csv compiler script I found (I can't locate it again at the moment). I've edited the question to show the code w/o this. I'm not sure what you mean by intermediate file.

Comment: I tried your code. The first example works as my code does, which like you mentioned will take a long time. The second code throws a file path into each line but the first five, which now shows a file path and the code you provided. The third does something similar - it replaces the first five lines with the code itself. See my edit #2 in the question.

Comment: @ckemmann - That is because ECHO must be on. Simply setting ECHO OFF eliminates the problem. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the fastest way to "Copy all lines from *.log files excepting the first 5 ones into *.log.new files":

```
for %%I in (*.log) do (

   rem Read from this file
   < "%%I" (

      rem Omit the first 5 lines
      for /L %%a in (1,1,5) do set /P "="

      rem Copy the rest
      findstr "^"

   rem And create the new file
   ) > "%%I.new"

)
```

Perhaps if you show us the format of the final .csv output file, we may also help you to create it in a faster way...

**EDIT**: The code below is what *I guess* generate the `results.csv` output file desired by the OP:

```
@echo off

(for %%I in (*.log) do (

   rem Read from this file
   < "%%I" (

      rem Omit the first 5 lines
      for /L %%a in (1,1,5) do set /P "="

      rem Copy the rest
      findstr "^"

   )

   echo ;

)) > results.csv
```

Comment: The final .csv output is similar to the original file. The first five lines are there, and the data entries continue from 00:00:01 to 23:59:59, after which point the first five lines are displayed again, and so on. This is due to the fact that the first script is simply copy-pasting all the .log files together as one. I tried using your script, however the processor stops before completing and the end result replaces each of the first five lines with `C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "="`.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... If the purpose of your code is to eliminate the first 5 lines from each input .log file, how is possible that these five lines appear in the final .csv file? Please, _show us_ a section of the `results.csv` output file that include small sections of two or three input files. _Edit your question_ to do so, do NOT post data nor extensive explanations in comments! Did you inserted an `@echo off` command at beginning of my code? Your example code does _not_ include any `@echo off`, so if you have such command in your code, then you must insert the same in my code.

Comment: After you modified your question, insert a small comment here just as advice of the change...

Comment: You're right, the purpose is to omit the first five lines when its being compiled. The reason they currently still show up is because your code, as I mentioned in my first comment, replaces each of the first five lines with `C:\Users\...\Desktop>set /P "="`. There is no `@echo off` in use in my code elsewhere (all the code I posted is all I am using). I updated the question to show what is currently happening and clarified regarding the .CSV and .LOG files.

Comment: This is strange. In your question you said you want to "generate a .csv file". I asked you (_twice_) what is the format of such .csv file in order to create it, but you never give us this information, so I can only guess. **`:/`** For example, a .csv file have columns separated by commas, but the data in your example does not include any comma... Anyway, see the edit in my answer.

Comment: If you look at my question you will see right at the top where I show an example of what the .csv file format looks like, as well as the original .log files. True, there are no commas, but that's not an issue, as .csv files can exist without them. The current code I'm using only serves to compile several .log files into one large file, for which .csv happens to be the format. I can see what you're trying to do with your edit, but I already have the code to compile to .csv. My issue lies with removing the first five lines in my .log files. The code I have takes too long.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103760/discussion-between-ckemmann-and-aacini).

Comment: Excuse me, but what you said in previous comment is not true. In the original question you explained that you want to omit the first 5 lines of _each file_, you posted a small section that includes the first 5 lines under `Original File` and then, under **`New File:`** header, you posted the same lines without the first 5. In your "example code" you included commands that output the name of each log file followed by a semicolon and the "new file" contents _in the same line_, and a semicolon after the file contents (?). You changed the "New File" header by "CSV Output" in a posterior edit!

Comment: Your process takes too long because there are two separated loops (eliminate 5 lines, compile all in one .csv) so, in order to speed up this process (that is what you asked for), both processes must be achieved in the same loop. The bottom line is this: my last code solve your problem in a very fast way. Isn't it?